# Measuring unusual death

Tags: poisson-distribution, outliers

Given the Prussian Horse Data here:
https://www.randomservices.org/random/data/HorseKicks.html

Is there a way to find out which corp has an unusually high number of deaths?

(Note that Prussian horse data is a classic data that conform to Poisson distribution)

Comment: How do you define *unusually high number of deaths*?